# Boot AMX on Glassfish4 throws InstanceNotFoundException

Tags: java, monitoring, glassfish-4

I am trying to boot the AMX bean at startup on a Glassfish 4 server. However, I get the following error message:

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: amx-support:type=boot-amx
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:816) 
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:310)
```

This is my call:

```
final MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
try {
    final ObjectName bootMBean = new ObjectName("amx-support:type=boot-amx");
    server.invoke(bootMBean, "bootAMX", null, null);
} catch (final MBeanException | ReflectionException | MalformedObjectNameException e) {
    ...
} catch (final InstanceNotFoundException e) {
    ...
}
```

Has anyone an idea where the problem could be?

Comment: May be related " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618820/jmx-mbeans-not-visible-after-deploy